# installing windowBuilder in myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, myeclipse

I am both an android developer and a swing developer. I usually use a adt-version of eclipse that was downloaded from google with android development tools, this version seems to be juno 4.2.1.

The problem is that the windowbuilder doesn't show up. No windowbuilder options under preferences, and no new editors available.

Previously i have been working on eclipse there i could install window Builder from market place> i want to build gui using drag and drop option from the design menu

And i know by default my eclipse should include window Builder but when i right click on my class file i can't find window Builder

I tried to import it externally but i cant find any option to import it just like in eclipse

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you mean "myeclipse" when you wrote "eclipse", since you have MyEclipse in the heading and as a keyword. If so, MyEclipse has come with WindowBuilder installed, for quite a few releases. Try New->Other and, in the wizard, type "window" in the filter box. You should see a couple of WindowBuilder options. If you do mean "eclipse" then you'd need to install. Go to Help->Eclipse Marketplace then search for "windowbuilder", click the Install button to install.

Comment: yeah i wished for myeclipse only.... see the problem is upon typing in filter box it gives no result

Comment: So, if there is nothing under New->Other, then you probably have a very old release of MyEclipse (you don't mention which release you are running). In this case you'd have to install Window Builder but to give instructions on how to do that (if there is a version of Window Builder that's compatible with your release of MyEclipse, which isn't guaranteed), I'd need to know the MyEclipse release. Alternatively upgrade to the latest release of MyEclipse (licenses are valid for a length of time and you can use any release within that time).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Eclipse Neon

- Eclipse Help-> Install New Software.
- enter this URL : http://download.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/WB/integration/4.6/
- Tick the Window Builder and click Add
- Complete the installation.